# Ruby/Rails - Remove ActiveAdmin from my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

I had a good time playing with Active Admin the administrative framework within my application.
http://activeadmin.info/

When I installed it I ran

```
rails g active_admin:install
rake db:migrate
rails g active_admin:resource product
```

and it generated alot of migrations and code within my application.

My question if I would like to go back and have everything that active_admin put into my application taken out, how would i do so?

Is there one 'rails active_admin:uninstall' command to get rid of everything or do I have to manually create migrations to delete all the tables and search through my code to see what it added?

Comment: Do you use version control?

Answer (score 44):

If you run the following code it should destroy active admin:

```
rails destroy active_admin:install
rails destroy active_admin:resource product
```

Comment: You don't even need the second line it seems.

Comment: Also, keep in mid that if you set up an `AdminUser` model when you added ActiveAdmin, this will destroy it, along with any methods you added to it.

Comment: Beware that some trash code will be left in 'routes.rb' and 'schema.rb'. Do a search for 'admin' and comment the unnecessary code, or it may cause errors later.

Comment: do i need to rollback the migration

Comment: Also remove `gem 'activeadmin'` from your gem file  or it will install again next time you bundle = ]

Answer (score 29):

Run this in terminal

```
rails destroy active_admin:install
```

Remove `gem 'activeadmin'` from your gemfile.

Delete the asset files from js and css folders if any remain

Delete any of these lines in Routes.rb

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

Then create a new migration with:

```
  drop_table :active_admin_comments
```

You may also need:

```
  drop_table :admin_notes
```

Or rollback the migrations by finding the relevant files `MoveAdminNotesToComments` and `CreateAdminNotes` in your `db/migrate` folder

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=the_version_number
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=the_version_number
```

Comment: The new drop migration is much cleaner than the rollback one, but thanks for making this good answer, everything is in here ;)

Comment: For everyone ease, I did :
`rails generate migration drop_active_admin_comments`
modified the migration like this:
``
class DropActiveAdminComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :active_admin_comments
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
``
``
bundle exec rake db:migrate
``
the table and indexes are gone ;)

Comment: Ok, I just don't know how to format a comment with code in it... so I've finally been rejected the right to reedit my previous comment :/

Comment: Oh and don't forget to remove the `gem 'active_admin' `  entry in your Gemfile once the `rails destroy active_admin:install` is done ;)

Comment: Yes. Thank you I have done this now. It works. Destroyed the active_admin and reinstalled the latest version. Rails and Windows 7 dont like eachother much :D

Answer (score 1):

You also need to delete all the active admin related js and css files in your assets folder after running
rails destroy active_admin:install